# Joining Two similar tables in SQL MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to Join two tables, but can't get the exact result. 
Table2 is to calculate requirement from default logics
table1 is to override the same data manually.
I need all data in Table1 as fixed and only the new or unmatched rows from table2 to be added to Table1

```
select * from table1
left outer join table2 on table1.project = table2.project and table1.function = table2.function and table1.Month = table2.Month and table1.Phase = table2.Phase and table1.Complexity = table2.Complexity;

CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Project` varchar(31), `function` varchar(8), `Month` datetime, `Phase` int, `Complexity` varchar(3), `Needed` float)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Project`, `function`, `Month`, `Phase`, `Complexity`, `Needed`)
VALUES
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.2),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-04-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-05-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-07-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-08-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-09-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-11-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-12-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`Project` varchar(31), `function` varchar(8), `Month` datetime, `Phase` int, `Complexity` varchar(6), `Needed` float)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`Project`, `function`, `Month`, `Phase`, `Complexity`, `Needed`)
VALUES
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-02-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-04-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-05-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-07-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-08-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-09-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-10-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-11-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'Clinical', '2019-12-01 00:00:00', 4, 'Low', 0.5),
    ('3D Templates - Project DeLorean', 'GSM', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 'Medium', 1.5)
;
```

Note First line in Table1 and Table2. Needed value in Both differs but I need only Table1 data. Last line in Table2 is newly added. I need that line in Table1

Comment: `select * from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.project = table2.project and table1.function = table2.function ;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`.  It is not clear how you are defining duplicates.  If it is on the first three columns, then:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 as t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 as t1
                  where t1.project = t2.project and
                        t1.function = t2.function and
                        t1.month = t2.month
                 );
```

If it is on all columns, then you simply want all rows in both tables and you can use `union`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 as t1
union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select t2.*
from table2 as t2;
```